# How do I install GD on my windows server version of PHP

Tags: php, gd, windows-server

I am running Windows Server 2003 and need to install a version of GD.

**Can anyone point out some instructions or advice?**

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Check `php_gd2.dll` is in your extension directory and uncomment `;extension=php_gd2.dll` of your `php.ini`.

Comment: Note, to uncomment, remove the semi-colon at the beggining of the line.

Comment: Do you have to restart any services or will PHP pick up the changes dynamically?

Comment: yes, restart apache with `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: And what if the php_gd2.dll is missing?

Comment: Note that if you have `extension_dir` set, the path must match. In newer PHP versions you don't enter the module dll name (extension_dir = php_gd2.dll) anymore. You enter only whats between php_ and .dll (`extension_dir = gd2` in this case). If a module doesn't work, I'm going to cmd and executing `php -m` to see the error message

Answer (score 30):

It was in my c:\xampp\php\php.ini

```
;extension=gd
```

This was commented out as you can see, removing ; and restarting apache server fixed my problem.

Comment: Working in Laravel, the `artisan server` must be restarted to reflect the changes made in `php.ini`. Uncommenting the line containing `;extension=gd` and restarting the server fixed my problem.

Comment: I literally tried everything, restarted XAMPP several times, but it didn't come to my mind that I was running the server via Artisan and I had to restart that ... thank you kind stranger!

Answer (score 15):

After PHP 8.0, GD extension name changed from php_gd2.dll to php_gd.dll

```
extension=php_gd.dll
```

https://php.watch/versions/8.0/gd2-gd-windows

Comment: This is the right answer for php8

Comment: Not sure why my PHP 8.1 default php.ini file had it with a 2, but I removed the "2" and restarted, and now I have GD details in my phpinfo()!

Answer (score 5):

To enable GD image library on PHP 8 open your php.ini file, find your extensions section and add into it:
extension=gd

### It will looks like:

**[ExtensionList]
extension=gd**

---

- I´m using Windows with PHP 8; so, after change restart your webserver.

** tks to this article: https://write.corbpie.com/how-to-enable-gd-library-with-xampp-php-8-on-windows/

Comment: Verified that this worked on Windows 10 / PHP 8.0.

Answer (score 4):

You need to edit your php.ini (found in your C:/PHP folder if you installed PHP here). Add the following line (or remove the ; before it if it exists in there):

extension=php_gd2.dll

Answer (score 3):

Issue was resolved. I am using XAPP.

I tried to search for "extension=php_gd2.dll" file in "php.ini" file but there was no such thing there (";extension=php_gd2.dll" was also not there with a semicolon).
Then I included the statement "extension=php_gd2.dll" myself in php.ini file.
Also, I downloaded the the file "extension=php_gd2.dll" from https://www.dll-files.com/php_gd2.dll.html and placed it in folder "C:\xampp\php" (there is also another folder C:\xampp\php\ext where other extensions reside but anyway this method did not work).
Then I restarted Apache and MySQL from xampp-control.exe.
It did NOT work.

I RESET all the changes I made in the previous step.

Tried the other method:

opened "php.ini" file (at C:\xampp\php) and looked for "extension=gd".
I noticed that there was a semicolon present with the searched word and it appeared as ";extension=gd". I removed semicolon. Saved the php.ini file. Stopped and restarted Apache from xampp-control.exe.

Now it works.

So what exactly was resolved?
When I was selecting logo image on wordpress at Customizing ▸ Default/Basic Setting ▸ Site Identity, I was unable to crop it earlier. After following the second step, it works. Now I can crop files.

Answer (score 1):

In **Windows** download related Debug Pack on php.net download page, it's contain most useful modules. After, uncomment related extension, for example to gd2:
`;extension=php_gd2.dll on php.ini` and uncomment `extension_dir = "ext"`.

Answer (score 1):

GD wasn't working for me even though it was installed in the extension folder. My issue was with the php.ini file which was referenced to extension=php_gd2.dll instead of extension=php_gd.dll.

Comment: So happy to found this as I had exactly the same issue. Switching to php_gd.dll solved the problem - thank you!