# composer require mgp25/instagram-php react/child-process (Not Working)

Tags: php, windows

When I run the command in my Windows command prompt `composer require mgp25/instagram-php react/child-process` all I get is:

```
Problem 1
    - mgp25/instagram-php v7.0.1 requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.
    - mgp25/instagram-php v7.0.0 requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for mgp25/instagram-php ^7.0 -> satisfiable by mgp25/instagram-php[v7.0.0, v7.0.1].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\Users\bill\Desktop\PHP\php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You need to install php's gd extension. See for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851011/how-do-i-install-gd-on-my-windows-server-version-of-php as a starter.

Answer (score 0):

1. open this file "C:\Users\bill\Desktop\PHP\php.ini" with any editor
2. find this line ";extension=gd2" (Ctrl+F)
3. remove ";" and save it