# error when installing the package on laravel via composer

Tags: php, excel, laravel, package

composer require maatwebsite/excel

```
Using version ^3.1 for maatwebsite/excel
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update maatwebsite/excel
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
```

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. Problem 1

```
    - maatwebsite/excel[3.1.27, ..., 3.2.x-dev] require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.16 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.16.0, 1.17.0, 1.17.1].
    - maatwebsite/excel 3.1.26 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.15 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.15.0, 1.16.0, 1.17.0, 1.17.1].
    - maatwebsite/excel[3.1.28, ..., 3.1.x-dev] require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.16.* -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.16.0].
    - maatwebsite/excel[3.1.0, ..., 3.1.25] require php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.15.0, ..., 1.17.1] require ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.
    - Root composer.json requires maatwebsite/excel ^3.1 -> satisfiable by maatwebsite/excel[3.1.0, ..., 3.2.x-dev].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\xampp\php\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable th `gd` extension in your `php.ini` file.

There's a line in there that probably looks like this:
`;extension=gd2` (or `;extension=gd`) and it needs to be `extension=gd2` (or `extension=gd`).

Answer (score 0):

[Laravel Server Requirements](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/installation#server-requirements) mention that BCMath, Ctype, JSON, Mbstring, OpenSSL, PDO, Tokenizer, and XML extensions are required. Most of the extensions are installed and enabled by default.

You can run the following command in Ubuntu to make sure the extensions are installed.

```
sudo apt install openssl php-common php-curl php-json php-mbstring php-mysql php-xml php-zip
```

PHP version-specific installation (if PHP 7.4 installed)

```
sudo apt install php7.4-common php7.4-bcmath openssl php7.4-json php7.4-mbstring
```

To see how to install it on windows, Please visit: [PHP gd extension install on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67148501/8142238)