# PHP built in web server + dynamic extension

Tags: php, gd, php-builtin-server

I'm using the **php** built-in server **(v 7.3.6)**.

Everything work perfectly. But when I add **gd** extension on the **php.ini** file (by removing the **";"**) nothing answer.

Commands like :

> "php -S localhost:8000" and "php -v"

no longer answer.

Can I add extension on the built-in server ?

Thank you for your time !

Comment: What is it that happens exactly when you type `php -v`, what does "no longer answer" mean?

Comment: The command no longer show me the version of php. It just wait for a new command.

Comment: What operating system are you running?

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 pro x64

Comment: OK, check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851011/how-do-i-install-gd-on-my-windows-server-version-of-php

Comment: Thx, this is exactly what I did but it's not working. Maybe it's because I'm using the php built-in server ?

Answer (score 0):

I found it, finally !

I had to uncomment the line : `extension_dir = "ext"`
Now php can find the extension :)

Thx you !